# Firebase Crashlytics without Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm working on an android app and because of privacy policy we should have opt in and opt out option for crashlytics and analytics. I've configured the crashlytics and everything works fine. When I disable crashlytics I don't receive any crash reports and when I enable I start receiving them again. When I disable analytics tho, I don't receive any crash report. Is this the behaviour we should expect, because I read somewhere that analytics gives just better crash reports not that it disables them.

manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

Build gradle dependencies

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21"
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Build gradle app

```
  //Firebase

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0'){
    because("You don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies")
}

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'){
    because("We want to be able to find and solve the crashes in the apps")
}

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'){
    because("It is required in order to make crashlytics work")
}

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'){
    because("It simplifies callbacks etc for firebase")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crashlytics can work without Analytics, but you may have something enabled that depends on Analytics. Not enough details here to tell.

Comment: I have nothing else besides those 2 dependencies from Firebase in my app. So I doubt if there is something more. What more details would be needed so that we could figure this out.

Comment: Just to clarify, when having firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled = true and firebase_analytics_collection_enabled = false, you don't get crash reports?

Comment: Exactly thats my problem. :)

Comment: have you resolve the issue? seem like same issue after integrated analytic, then works. but the official doc seem like crashlytic is independent. but there is a blog:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/crashlytics-analytics-together.html